# Дублирование формы

Tags: php, форма

Например, есть страница addnews.php с формой для добавления новости на сайт. Есть страница editnews.php с той же формой для редактирования определенной новости. Как мне сделать одну форму для обоих страниц, чтобы не дублировать? Допустим, если на странице addnews.php мне надо удалить/добавить какое-нить поле, придется и на странице editnews.php тоже менять... а это как-то не красиво получается... 21 век фсйо-токи )

Конечно, можно сделать так:

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo !empty($title) ? $title : null; ?>" />
```

Но это не очень красиво... Может, есть более гибкий способ?

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант А:** выделите в отдельный файл **статичную** часть формы и подключайте его там, где это необходимо.
**Вариант Б:** напишите функцию, которая будет генерировать форму в нужном формате на основе переданных в нее параметров.
Эту функцию выделите в отдельный файл и подключайте его там, где это необходимо.

Comment: в файле editnews в форму мне нужно подставлять значение выбранной новости. например, <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /> . А если в файле form.php я это пропишу, addnews.php будет ругаться типа нет переменной $title

Comment: Исправил ответ.